# Why do people put { " " } in their React / JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have this in some React documentation, as well as screencasts. People will write `{ " " }` inside of their JSX templates.

Why do they do this? It looks like they are using it as an alternative to line breaks, but I don't see that explicitly explained anywhere.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is used to put an explicit space in a text block, since leading and trailing spaces are ignored at compile/transformation time when there is another tag.

Example:

```html
<div>
 Text
 <a>some Text</a>
</div>
```

Will result with `Textsome Text` on the screen. *(see the missing space)*

```html
<div>
 Text{' '}
 <a>some Text</a>
</div>
```

Will result as wanted with `Text some Text` on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the example you had in mind. If it is not, can you provide a code example!

Comment: What's wrong with writing `Text <a>some Text</a>`? It will keep the white space.

Comment: @CosminAbabei Yes, that would keep the whitespace intact, but sometimes your line of text can become quite long, and you need to split it. So the most "obvious" split is on the `a` tag but that removes the space, so a forced manual space is needed

Comment: does using `&nbsp;` not work? or would that have to be wrapped in curly brackets too? like `{&nbsp;}`

Comment: @JeffSpicoli `&nbsp;` would stay in the compiled code however, it'll lead to a very different behavior than the above. The above ensures to keep a normal breaking space

Answer (score 4):

It is used to add some leading or trailing spaces

```
render() {
  return ( 
    <div>
      My name is{' '}
      <span> Piyush </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```