# What is {' '} in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was working on a collaborative project and there is a lot of `{' '}` used.

Examples -

```
<Text>
     {' '}
     {constant.Messages.PointText.hey} {this._user.first_name || this._user.business_name}!{' '}
</Text>
```

```
<Text>
     {' '}
     {constant.Messages.PointText.redeem}{' '}
</Text>
```

`constant.` is text as a constant.

Comment: It's a quick and dirty way to add whitespace in jsx

Comment: It's precisely what it looks like--a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do people put { " " } in their React / JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547558/why-do-people-put-in-their-react-jsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{' '}` syntax to insert intentional whitespace (or tabs, newlines, etc).

Answer (score 2):

It will add an empty space into the dom.

Answer (score 1):

> This is used to put an explicit space in a text block, since leading
>   and trailing spaces are ignored at compile/transformation time when
>   there is another tag.

refer this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547558/why-do-people-put-in-their-react-jsx)

Comment: There is an option under question to flag as a duplicate. This is the way to go instead of quoting inside a new answer, unless you want to add relevant additional information.